# how i can change year in buddist year in moment,js

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, momentjs

I am using  [bootstrap datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker). Its need [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js).

To make it local I have use this [moment with locale](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js)

I need my year should be **Buddhist year-2016** means `2559(2016+543)`. How can I achieve this using moment.

My html is :

```js
$('#startDate').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
  locale: 'th',
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.42/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.42/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-6 date">
  <input type='text' class="form-control" id='startDate' />
</div>
```

I need this:

[image]

Comment: you can use `minDate: moment().add(543, 'years')`. But this is just a hack. The actual logic will be little more complex

Comment: @Rajesh this is wrong. days will differ